# Can I connect Alteryx to CosmoDB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, alteryx

I have a project where my end users are using Alteryx to combine data sources and import into SQL server. We are investigating changing SQL server to CosmoDB but I'm not sure if connecting to CosmoDB is supported by Alteryx.

Do anyone know if there is a connector? Am I overthinking this? I don't know Alteryx very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no dedicated connector from Azure Cosmos DB.

However, the [Azure Cosmos DB ODBC driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql/odbc-driver) enables you to connect to Azure Cosmos DB using BI analytics tools.

Also, there is an existing [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/) for Cosmos DB, it should be possible to access it through a [Downloaded tool](https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Knowledge-Base/APIs-in-Alteryx-cURL-and-Download-Tool/ta-p/31522). You can suggest in the idea section of [Alteryx Community](https://community.alteryx.com/t5/Alteryx-Product-Ideas/idb-p/product-ideas) to request one.